# Average using Excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table which has 4 columns and 2 rows.

In each of the 4 inputs in row 1, we have a $ amount our company has (100000, 150000, 200000, 175000).

In row 2 we have the amount of product which we've been able to purchase.
Note: products doesn't have a fixed price, and is constantly changing.
Row 2 has the values (10000, 20000, 22000, 18000 respectively for the above $ amounts).

I want a cell, where if I input the dollars I have, it will give me the average amount of product I can buy based on the historical data.

Also, I need the formula to be dynamic, i.e. once I add a fifth column, it takes the average using 5 datapoints, instead of the previous 4.

I tried various look up/index formulas.

Answer (score 2):

You want FORECAST.LINEAR():

```
=FORECAST.LINEAR(C6,2:2,1:1)
```

[image]